# How to run a C# program without needing Console.ReadLine()?

Tags: console.readline

After I run a program, I always need to add Console.ReadLine(); to the end in order for the program results to not go away. If I were to code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
  Console.ReadLine(); // I need this for the console to stay open.
}
```

I noticed in watching youtube videos that some are able to run their code without the Console.ReadLine() method.  How do I go about doing this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From Visual Studio, you can press `Ctrl+F5` to run your program, that will run without debugging.
You can also use `Console.ReadKey()` as an alternative to `Console.ReadLine()` for keeping the console visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run another thread. Console stay while it lasts.
EDIT:
I just put the sample code here for better readability:

```
var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(
    () => {while (true) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);}
);
thread.Start();
```

Comment: i know it's old and you probably found an answer, but for others looking for it: 
`var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => { while (true) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); });
   thread.Start();` It holds console (because program is still running) until you close it manually.